# Call a stored procedure in a trigger? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TIME_CHECK
as

JOUR date;
HEURE date;
BEGIN

select to_char(sysdate, 'DAY'), to_char(sysdate,'HH.MI.SS')
into jour, heure
FROM DUAL   
WHERE JOUR = to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') AND HEURE = to_char(sysdate,'HH.MI.SS');

if (jour not between 'SUNDAY' AND 'FRIDAY') and (heure not between '08.00.00' AND '22.00.00')
or (jour !='SATURDAY') AND (HEURE NOT BETWEEN '08.00.00' AND '12.00.00')

then raise_application_error(-20111,'OUT OF BUSINESS HOURS');

end if; 

end;
```

-- TRIGGER

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mod_job_history

before insert or update  on JOB_HISTORY

for each row

BEGIN

CALL TIME_CHECK 
---??????
        
END mod_job_history;
```

My procedure is supposed to valid if the user is trying to do something on business hours or not and the trigger is to be sure that the user is not allowed to insert or update the table job_history on business hours?

I've been working on it for several hours and I cannot find what's wrong help plz and how should I call my procedure via my trigger

thank you

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Comment: Oracle Sql developper

Comment: Did you tell us what was wrong?

Comment: My trigger is incomplete I dont really know how to call my procedure properly

Comment: Just write `TIME_CHECK;` to call the procedure. The procedure, though, has severe issues, so you won't get the result you are expecting.

Comment: can you be more specific about whats wrong with the procedure? That's my first sql course

Comment: 1. The `WHERE` clause. You don't need any and as is it won't ever match, because JOUR and EURE are null at that moment. 2. Don't rely on getting English names. Use the third parameter in `TO_CHAR` to specify the language. 3. 'SUNDAY' starting with 'S' is greater than 'FRIDAY' which starts with an 'F', so your `BETWEEN` is wrong. There may be more.

Comment: As to the trigger: I'd not make this a BEFORE ROW but a BEFORE STATEMENT trigger, i.e. remove `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: how can jour (day) and heure(hours) can be linked with the actual day and time?

Comment: 4. your `IF` logic is wrong. 5. JOUR and HEURE are dates, but you are trying to fill them with strings. 6. The time format is wrong (12 hours instead of 24).

Comment: `heure varchar2(8) := to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss');`

Comment: The variables JOUR and HEURE are both defined as DATE, but you are selecting into them the result of TO_CHAR, which is a STRING.  This forces oracle to do an implicit TO_DATE on the result of the TO_CHAR(SYSDATE…).    So you are not getting what you think you are.  But of course, you are really not getting anything at all because “WHERE JOUR = to_char(sysdate, 'DAY')” will evaluate FALSE because at that point JOUR is NULL. Then your IF statement is compareing STRINGS, not dates or times. Remember that a DATE type _includes_ time.  When doing date/time comparisons, don't convert to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `TIME_CHECK;`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER mod_job_history
before insert or update  on JOB_HISTORY
for each row
BEGIN
  TIME_CHECK;
END mod_job_history;
/
```

Also, your procedure will not work as intended as `JOUR` is initially set to `NULL` and the you are comparing against it in the `WHERE` clause.

You can use the procedure below (which will work regardless of which language you use):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE TIME_CHECK
AS
  day  PLS_INTEGER := TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW');
  time INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := (SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) DAY TO SECOND;
BEGIN
  IF ( day IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) -- Monday to Friday
     AND time BETWEEN INTERVAL '8' HOUR
                  AND INTERVAL '22' HOUR
     )
     OR
     ( day = 5 -- Saturday
     AND time BETWEEN INTERVAL '08' HOUR
                  AND INTERVAL '12' HOUR
     )
  THEN
    -- Inside business hours
    NULL;
  ELSE
    raise_application_error(-20111,'OUT OF BUSINESS HOURS');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95632a8c8176f57476916fe7898d5c98)*